# Spring integration: handle http error with oubound gateway

Tags: spring-integration

How can I handle exceptions in an http outbound gateway?
When i receive status code 500 or 400..., an exception is shown. So What  should I do to handle http error using spring integration.

My configuration is like:

```
<int:inbound-channel-adapter channel="quakeinfotrigger.channel"
    expression="''">
    <int:poller fixed-delay="60000"></int:poller>
</int:inbound-channel-adapter>


<int:channel id="quakeinfo.channel">
    <int:queue capacity="10" />
</int:channel>

<int:channel id="quakeinfotrigger.channel"></int:channel>

<int:channel id="error.channel">
<int:queue capacity="10" />
</int:channel>

<int:service-activator input-channel="error.channel"
    ref="httpResponseErrorHandler" method="handleMessage">
    <int:poller fixed-delay="5000"></int:poller>
</int:service-activator>

<int:service-activator input-channel="quakeinfo.channel"
    ref="httpResponseMessageHandler" method="handleMessage">
    <int:poller fixed-delay="5000"></int:poller>
</int:service-activator>

<int:gateway id="requestGateway" service-interface="standalone.HttpRequestGateway"
    default-request-channel="quakeinfotrigger.channel" error-channel="error.channel" />

<int-http:outbound-gateway id="quakerHttpGateway"
    request-channel="quakeinfotrigger.channel" url="http://fooo/mmmm/rest/put/44545454"
    http-method="PUT" expected-response-type="java.lang.String" charset="UTF-8"
    reply-timeout="5000" reply-channel="quakeinfo.channel">
</int-http:outbound-gateway>

<bean id="httpResponseMessageHandler" class="standalone.HttpResponseMessageHandler" />
<bean id="httpResponseErrorHandler" class="standalone.HttpResponseErrorHandler" />
```

I would like to know why exception does'nt go to reply-channel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I would like to know why exception does'nt go to reply-channel

Because it's natural to handle exceptions as, er, Exceptions.

There are (at least) two ways to handle exceptions in Spring Integration.

1. Add an `error-channel` and associated flow on whatever starts your flow (e.g. a gateway). The error channel gets an `ErrorMessage` with a `MessagingException` payload; the exception has two properties - the `failedMessage` and the `cause`.
2. Add a `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice` (or a custom advice) to the gateway; see [Adding Behavior to Endpoints](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/#message-handler-advice-chain).

Comment: An error-channel has already added to gateway but always a HttpServerErrorException is thrown, My config file is updated

Comment: Because you're not using the gateway; the inbound adapter is sending directly to `quakeinfotrigger.channel`. You could also add an `error-channel` to the inbound adapter's poller; then you wouldn't need the gateway at all.

Comment: How to read http_status code from error-channel, because i should handle each error seprately.

Comment: The error message payload (`MessagingException`) has a `cause` that will be an `HttpStatusCodeException` (client or server subclass) with properties like `statusCode`, `statusText` etc.

Comment: Hi Gary, the link is broken. I need help as my integration flow is throwing 500 error and missing the message from the actual external service. I created CustomResponseErrorHandler, as shown in the answer below by Arun, and added errorHandler =that bean. This is working. But do I need such class, where there is no much implemenation? if so, how can I make it understandable. The below class is almost empty. please can you help

Comment: I fixed the link; if you still have questions, ask a new one; questions in comments don't help the community finding questions/answers.

Answer (score 1):

If the response status code is in the HTTP series **CLIENT_ERROR** or **SERVER_ERROR**, **HttpClientErrorException** or **HttpServerErrorException** are thrown respectively. Hence the response doesn't go to reply channel

> Refer [DefaultResponseErrorHandler](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/client/DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java)
>   Methods: hasError and handleError

To Handle these exceptions, create your own CustomResponseErrorHandler and override contents of hasError and handlerError methods.

```
public class CustomResponseErrorHandler extends DefaultResponseErrorHandler {

    @Override
    public boolean hasError(ClientHttpResponse response) throws IOException {
        return hasError(getHttpStatusCode(response));
    }

    protected boolean hasError(HttpStatus statusCode) {
        return /*Status Code to be considered as Error*/ ;
    }

    @Override
    public void handleError(ClientHttpResponse response) throws IOException { /* Handle Exceptions */
    }
}
```

And add *error-handler* to your http-outbound-gateway

```
<int-http:outbound-gateway id="quakerHttpGateway"
    request-channel="quakeinfotrigger.channel" url="http://fooo/mmmm/rest/put/44545454"
    http-method="PUT" expected-response-type="java.lang.String" charset="UTF-8"
    reply-timeout="5000" reply-channel="quakeinfo.channel" error-handler="customResponseErrorHandler">
</int-http:outbound-gateway>
```

Comment: I have tried with this code, but it is not invoking customResponseHandler. Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

I had occurred the same problem.I threw my own customized Exception and error message but always got "500 Internal server error".It's because there will be no reply message and "reply" is timeout when throw Exception.So I handle the exception by subscribing error-channel and then reply by myself.

```
Message<?> failedMessage = exception.getFailedMessage();
Object replyChannel = new MessageHeaderAccessor(failedMessage).getReplyChannel();
if (replyChannel != null) {
    ((MessageChannel) replyChannel).send(MessageFactory.createDataExchangeFailMessage(exception));
}
```